# TCPDUMP IP UNKNOWN

Tags: tcpdump, udp

I am seeing this in the tcpdump output

21:32:51.580969 IP UNKNOWN.9998 > 255.255.255.255.9998: UDP, length 12

What does 'IP UNKNOWN' mean? Is something hiding the ip address?

Thanks

Comment: To provide a decent answer it would help to see the `tcpdump` command that you're using

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you don't use the option `-n` for tcpdump which would show the plain IP addresses. Without this option it will try to get the hostname for the IP address by doing a DNS reverse lookup. And the hostname for this IP might just be "UNKNOWN".

Comment: That was the problem, using -n fixed it, thanks